# Do I need to check for multitasking? iOS

Tags: ios, multitasking

I found in one project this kind of code:

```
   if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] isMultitaskingSupported]) {
   ...        
   }
```

But, as I know, multitasking is supported since iOS 4.0. 
Is this sometimes can be useful to check for multitasking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you don't need to check for multitasking. All current iOS devices support it and you can't submit an app to the App Store without multitasking support.

Answer (score 2):

You can forget about it if not plan to develop for really old iOS device...